# Unable to Save New Link in Database for Selected Visa Number File and Selected Ticket

Tags: vb.net

I am currently facing an issue with saving new links in the database for the selected visa number file and selected ticket. I have a function in my code (UpdateData) that is responsible for updating the recruitment status information, including file paths for visa and ticket files.

Here's my code :

UpdateData

```
    Public Sub UpdateData(recordID As Integer, name As String, contact As String, email As String, passport As String, nationality As String, position As String, company As String, basic As String, food As String, housing As String, transportation As String, offer As String, medical As String, remarks As String, visaPosition As String, visaNumber As String, visaNumberFile As String, airline As String, arrival As String, ticketFile As String, assignLocation As String, status As String, agency As String)
        Using connection As OleDbConnection = DatabaseManager.GetConnection()
            connection.Open()
            Using transaction As OleDbTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction()
                Try
                    Dim commandString As String = "UPDATE recruitmentStatus SET [selectedName]=?, [selectedContact]=?, [selectedEmail]=?, [selectedPassport]=?, [selectedNationality]=?, [selectedPosition]=?, [selectedCompany]=?, [selectedBasic]=?, [selectedFood]=?, [SelectedHousing]=?, [selectedTransportation]=?, [SelectedOffer]=?, [selectedMedical]=?, [selectedRemarks]=?, [selectedVisaposition]=?, [selectedVisanumber]=?, [selectedVisanumberFile]=?, [selectedAirline]=?, [selectedArrival]=?, [selectedTicket]=?, [selectedAssignlocation]=?,[selectedStatus]=?, [selectedAgency]=?  WHERE [ID]=?"

                    Using command As New OleDbCommand(commandString, connection, transaction)

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedName", name)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedContact", contact)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedEmail", email)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedPassport", passport)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedNationality", nationality)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedPosition", position)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedCompany", company)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedBasic", basic)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedFood", food)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SelectedHousing", housing)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedTransportation", transportation)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SelectedOffer", offer)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedMedical", medical)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedRemarks", remarks)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedVisaposition", visaPosition)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedVisanumber", visaNumber)

                        ' get SaveFileAndGetPath the new file paths
                        Dim newVisaNumberFile As String = SaveFileAndGetPath(name, visaNumberFile, "Visa")
                        Dim newTicketFile As String = SaveFileAndGetPath(name, ticketFile, "Ticket")

                        ' Update new file paths
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedVisanumberFile", newVisaNumberFile)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedAirline", airline)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedArrival", arrival)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedTicket", newTicketFile)


                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedAssignlocation", assignLocation)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedStatus", status)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("selectedAgency", agency)
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", recordID)

                        Dim result As Integer = command.ExecuteNonQuery()

                        If result > 0 Then
                            transaction.Commit()
                            MessageBox.Show("Data has been successfully updated.")
                            clearData()
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("No records were updated. Please check the ID and data.")
                        End If
                    End Using
                Catch ex As OleDbException
                    transaction.Rollback()
                    MessageBox.Show("Database Error: " & ex.Message, "Database Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    transaction.Rollback()
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

SaveFileAndGetPath

```
    Private Function SaveFileAndGetPath(candidateName As String, filePath As String, fileType As String) As String
        Try
            Dim baseFolder As String = "F:\HR Main Folder\Recruitment\Recruitment Selected Candidate files"
            Dim candidateFolder As String = Path.Combine(baseFolder, candidateName)

            If Not Directory.Exists(candidateFolder) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(candidateFolder)
            End If

            Dim subFolder As String = ""
            Select Case fileType
                Case "Visa"
                    subFolder = "Visa"
                Case "Ticket"
                    subFolder = "Ticket"
            End Select

            Dim subFolderPath As String = Path.Combine(candidateFolder, subFolder)

            If Not Directory.Exists(subFolderPath) Then
                Directory.CreateDirectory(subFolderPath)
            End If

            Dim fileName As String = $"{fileType}-{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy")}{Path.GetExtension(filePath)}"
            Dim destinationPath As String = Path.Combine(subFolderPath, fileName)

            File.Copy(filePath, destinationPath)
            File.Delete(filePath)
            Return destinationPath
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return String.Empty
        End Try
    End Function
```

I use the SaveFileAndGetPath function to save and retrieve the new paths for the visa number file and ticket file. However, despite the code execution completing without errors, the new links are not being saved in the database.

save the new link, i'm getting always empty in my db

Comment: When you debug, what specific behavior(s) do you observe?  Is no record being updated at all?  Or is a record being updated with unexpectedly empty values?  Or something else?  What value does `ExecuteNonQuery()` return?  What values are being used in populating the query parameters?  Are they all what you expect?

Comment: @David i try to use this MessageBox.Show(result) i'm getting 1 only then this message MessageBox.Show("Data has been successfully updated.")

Comment: Then it seems that a record has been successfully updated.  In that case what specific indication do you have that there is a problem at all?

Comment: Yah that's also my in mind however why i check in db the 2 subject column in table is empty other information are stored

Comment: What is "the 2 subject column"?  The word "subject" appears exactly nowhere in the code shown.  If you're not updating the value in a particular column then the value in that particular column won't be updated.  This is expected behavior.  Please clarify the problem.

Comment: selectedVisanumberFile and selectedTicket are empty

Comment: The function `SaveFileAndGetPath` silently swallows exceptions and returns an empty string in this case. This could explain the observed behavior. Display the exception in a MessageBox.

Comment: @UnknownSource: And [as already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679497/unable-to-save-new-link-in-database-for-selected-visa-number-file-and-selected-t?noredirect=1#comment136946385_77679497), when you debug, what exact values do you observe in the variables being used to populate the query?  [As pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77679497/unable-to-save-new-link-in-database-for-selected-visa-number-file-and-selected-t?noredirect=1#comment136946526_77679497), your method explicitly returns an empty string.  So why is it surprising that an empty string is saved?

Comment: @UnknownSource: This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: I fully support what David says. See also: [Tutorial: Learn to debug Visual Basic code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/visual-basic/tutorial-debugger).

Comment: @David and Olivier,

I have not yet get a solution despite of try and error regarding this code structure issue. However, I have found alternative solutions to achieve the desired results. Thank you for your time and attention.